# roslib - Phyton

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I create a Phyton project within the ar_pose package.
I tried to import roslib to my Phyton program with

import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('ar_pose')

,but get the answer that he could not found the module roslib.

Is roslib a own package which I have to download?

Thanks!

(ROS electric)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40610/roslib---phyton/) by [Janina](https://answers.ros.org/users/1871/janina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your PYTHON_PATH needs to be set up correctly. Did you source setup.bash?

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1